# How to output JSON results as an integer

Tags: php, json, twitter

The problem I've been having is i'm using a twitter end-point to capture certain keywords in tweets but I'm not getting any numerical value in the results to say how many results there are.  Below is the code used:

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ps4&rpp=100&geocode=43.652527,-79.381961,10mi&geocode=49.263588,-123.138565,10mi&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed');
$search = json_decode($response);
$items = array();

foreach ($search->results as $item) {
      $items[] = array('text' => '@'.$item->from_user.': '.$item->text);
 }
 $data = array('item' => $items);

 header('Content-Type: application/json');

 echo json_encode($data);

 ?>
```

The output that I'm getting is just showing user name and tweet.

```
 {"item":[{"text":"@detikcom: Gocekan PES 2014 Bakal Semakin Lincah di PS4 http:\/\/t.co\/CtrUtOf0GI via @detikinet"}}]}
```

What I want is a total number of mentions in a single integer to display.  I can't find anything that would put my on the right path, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is your issue getting the data you need from twitter, or encoding an integer value in your `$data`?

Comment: it would be encoding an integer value.  The data from twitter is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `count($items)`? You could do something like this:

```
$data = array('item' => $items, 'itemCount' => count($items));
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's not outputting any numerical value.  Let me look into the PHP document to see if I can get it working. Thanks BTW